# Merge a folder of images that don't have overlapping elements but do align at edges

Tags: alignment, batch-processing, merge

In essence, I'm wondering if there's a solution on the Mac to solve a jigsaw for me. I have several folders of images scraped from a slippy-tile map and want to merge them together into a single image.

One edge should match another edge. If the edges matches several (e.g. they cover a blank white area of the image, deduction from the other edges matching could be used).

I've tried `Photomerge` in *PhotoShop* but have come to realise it looks for overlapping areas. This is a distinctly different problem for a computer to solve as the parts that match require a different logic. I've come across some uncompiled CLI tools on *GitHub* that suggest they do something similar but are way beyond my abilities to get a binary working on a mac.

All my images are at the same resolution. Nothing needs to be scaled or rotated to align. The majority are square ratio images, except for some edge images. Nothing will overlap. The full/sources images (which I can't access) have literally been sliced into many smaller images that I need to reconstruct.

Due to the method jpeg uses to compress, some leeway would be needed for exact pixel matching at edges. In other words, it would need to be able to tolerate approximate pixel matching of areas rather than exact matches, or predict a slight shift in hue or brightness might match as a neighbouring pixel rather than looking for a duplicate. I'm also trying to avoid online solutions as I have dozens of folders containing hundreds of images that need to be aligned and merged.

I think it's easy to understand from the description but here's an example of four images that should clarify the situation I'm in:

[image]

### Update:

Some further research has found a few CLI tools that provide some solutions in this area for map images. Rather than solving any image matching, they just merge a collection of photos based on clues in the filename about their location.

While my images have been sourced from slippy-map type pages, they aren't actually maps and don't have longitude or latitude relevance that could be extracted from the filename. They do provide clues to their location in their filename but, as mentioned earlier, CLI type programming is way beyond my abilities to create a merged image based on filenames such as:

```
page=1;zoom=50;rect=512,768,256,256;jpeg.jpg
```

*rect=512,768,256,256* being the pertinent part. It contains the information about where the slice was extracted from, in pixels, from the original. Unfortunately this will become a programming/cli question then, which may be more relevant on the main stackexchange site. I'm hoping there's some existing graphic utility using pixel matching that already solve this. Otherwise I'm in for an even more powerful headache.

### Update 2:

I had to abandon this as - with any job - I had only so much time to complete it. For anybody who comes across this in the meantime, you might see from the last update, as well as some comments and answers that the most feasible solution - if you're so inclined as to have a good grasp of programming basics - is to use something like *Python* or *Ruby* alongside *Imagemagick* (or the *PIL* library if using *Python*). This is feasible for this situation as the filenames I was using specify the location of where each image has been sliced from the original. We then don't need to concern ourselves with matching image edges at all, we just need to be able to work computer voodoo to make a script that merges images into one based on the coordinates in the filename of each.

With this solution, however, it's beyond graphic design theory or practicalities and into the murky underbelly of programming. If anybody comes across an image utility that manages to avoid this in the future, I'd love if they'd add it as an answer below to help others.

Comment: CLI is not really that difficult, and it's totally worth to learn it. imagemagick can do what you need and they have quite a good help page: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/

Comment: @AAGD I use CLI stuff all the time - particularly for GIS - and find it takes me hours to accomplish anything if there's not a similar example I can tweak. I just don't have a natural intuition for it. Funnily enough, I was working on an imagemagick solution just now but was hoping an existing utility was already in place.

Comment: In PhotoShop you could also try File > Automate > ContactSheet 2 with zero margin and if filenames are in order.

Comment: A nice idea, alas, the filenames are as I've shown in the example and provide no sense of order. There's too many files to rename manually.

Comment: Sorry, also zero margin wouldn't work anyway...

Comment: The problem will always be the sorting. Renaming the files might be the easiest way to get them in order, I often use A Better Finder Rename for this. You can perform a sequence of rename actions, and save it as a preset. If you pad the coordinates with zeros (0000, 0256, 0512), the files will sort automatically. Copy/pasting the file list to imagemagick will then really be easy.

Comment: @AAGD - Although my question pertained to a specific job, I was interested in the possibility of image merging by edge matching slices in the wider sense too. Jobs where filenames won't always contain contextual help. With that in mind, the question didn't necessarily hope for a filename and script based solution. That said, I'd updated the question to point out that, in this particular case, a sorting-based solution was looking like the best path to take, yes.

Answer (score 0):

If they align to a regular rectangular grid, then a quick sort on top, right (`512` and `768`) would immediately give a tile order. If I was to attempt to automate this, I would probably:

- run a regexp or write a quick script to to pull the `rect=512,768,256,256;jpeg.jpg` portion out of the source.
- remove `rect=` and find+replace the `;` with a `,` and the path to where the images are
- import the resultant comma-delimited file into a database

I would now have the information in a form I could process: (`select * from table sort by top, right`) in order to sort and/or rename the files in a way that allows me to use whatever folder-to-tile image software I choose. It would be fairly trivial to create a query that exports to a text file which I could use to create a command-line to run a process or provide an input file for a process or copy the original files to a temp folder with tile-order filenames (`c:\foo\tile_00_00.jpg`)

As far as a software option: the `montage` command for imagemagik might work (http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/)

Comment: Thanks @Yorik. I think I've got the theory side covered ok. There's many ways of doing this and it's straightforward to think of how to go about doing them, but not how to make workable code in the time I have available (as my programming abilities are pretty horrible). I was hoping there was an existing image matching solution for this, not dissimilar to `Photomerge` in *Photoshop* and the reason I put this in a Graphic Design rather than Stack Exchange itself.

Answer (score 0):

> I realize this is an old question, but it was bumped by the community and doesn't really have a direct answer.

As long asyou know how many images you have in one row , it's pretty simple using [imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/index.php):

```bash
cd "path/to input/folder"
montage -mode concatenate -tile 3x -background 'transparent' *.png ../merged.png
```

- `-tile 3x` defines the number of columns basically. Check the example gif below. 3 images per row.
- `-background 'transparent'` is only necessary if you're going from like png to png and you want to retain transparency. Not needed if you're merging jpegs. Remove it if you're going from png to jpeg.
- `*.png` makes it look for `.png` files in the input folder
- `../merged.png` →

  - `../` = one folder up from the input folder <sup><sub>(image is saved
    next to input folder)</sub></sup>
  - `merged` = filename
  - `.png` = output format

---

**Example**

I sliced up an image using PS. This is just me making sure we are all on the same page on what the sliced images look like:

[image]

Then I ran the command I gave above and this is the result:

[image]
*The slight white fringing was there in the image slices. It's just more apparent in the big merged image against a dark background.*

Comment: is this choosing an order based on filenames or actually using some sort of matching algorithm to find neighbouring seams?

Comment: @biscuitstack just filenames. I feel like you'd need like a sci-fi movie AI to do it otherwise.

Comment: I'm afraid the question is concerned with edge-matching rather than filenames. I did cautiously open up the possibility of a solution with filenames but with the caveat that it's pretty impractical (with an example filename) and would be a programming question rather than graphic design then. Interestingly, I disagree with the immensity of the algorithm needed to do this - it wouldn't necessarily even need to be AI - I can think of one logical way of approaching it.

Comment: @biscuitstack, yea, if whatever exports the slices can't do it in an orderly manner or there's no way to batch rename then afterwards (like by creation date or something), using filenames to decide the order is a no go for sure... Unless you want to manually go through each file renaming them. The issue I see with edge matching is the lack of overlap. There's nothing to really match. I think you said it might have something to do with maps or something and I'm just picturing a map with like a terrain that is basically just a blob of different textures

Comment: ...and how it would  be just impossible for any kind of algorithm to match the correct edges with 100% success rate. Even an AI or a human would have to guess what goes where. Of course, it does depend on the image a bit, but also if we think of something simpler like the Simpsons logo, the bottom pixels of the first square and the top pixels of the fourth square are not identical because there's no overlap and the S has curves. If we were to divide a plain square into slices, you could probably match the edges, but I don't see it being possible in a real-world scenario.

Comment: Here's a very zoomed image where I isolated a top section between slice-01 and slice-04 from my answer: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1hID.png) - How would a script decide that these edges are a match? We know they are, but in terms of raw pixel data, they are not a match. If there was some overlap, I can totally imagine a script matching the edges, but without any, not so much. All that said, I'm the furthest from an expert when it comes to edge matching and whatnot, so I could also just be totally wrong.

Comment: I don't know how familiar you are with programming but closest match is a common solution. It allows for leeway if the user accepts results may not always be accurate. There's a definite logical flow to it so it's not the most extravagant algorithm to work through.

Comment: e.g. as one example... if you break the left side of each tile into 10 x 10 pixel values that are given an averaged RGB array of 3 values. Which of these has the least different from the 10 x 10 averages pixel values of the right side of one tile? You can start with that logic and begin a sorting algorithm to work out a most likely match. It allows for jpeg artifacts, etc. There's a lot of fine tuning and caveats there (that's just a first step) but sci-fi level AI or AI in general aren't even a necessity.

Comment: @biscuitstack, guessing is always guessing. I don't know how many slices we are talking about or what the big picture would look like, but I think you're being overly optimistic. Something like the Simpsons logo, with a small number of slices, sure... maybe... but a map is never going to work. Maybe with like 4 slices, but if we're talking about way more than that... There's just no way. I mean, if you ever make it work, I definitely want to see it. But there's no way.

Comment: I disagree on most of your points just now but perhaps we'll agree to disagree. There isn't enough space here, it's discouraged as a long conversation space, and this isn't a programming question so this is a very big tangent. But thanks for the discussion.