# Fitting multiple layers of the same size without overlapping

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I have a map that I have assembled from many equally sized squares and now wonder if there is a way to make photoshop automatically fit all of the pieces together to remove any gaps and overlaps instead of me moving them by one-two pixel at a time.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Something like this perhaps? https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/136908/2332

Comment: If there's no overlap I think your out of luck unless the grid images are ordered by file name in some way.  You'd need some sort of AI to do it otherwise. Not a simple thing at all.  See the related question that Joonas mentioned.

Comment: That is I think almost 300 pieces, but I think I'd personally rather rename  the files if necessary rather than manually align them.