# merge images that align at the edges but are slightly rotated at random angles

Tags: alignment, merge

So I have four images that line up together each image is slightly rotated to varying degrees. If they all had the same rotation then I could just employ the techniques described at [Merge a folder of images that don't have overlapping elements but do align at edges](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/101004/165630) or, if they had some overlap I could make use of image stitching (Photo Merge in Adobe Lightroom) but they don't have any overlap.

Here's a picture showing what I mean:

[image]

Here are the individual images (uncropped):

- https://www.frostjedi.com/L-4-1872-Sheet-1.jpg (bottom right)
- https://www.frostjedi.com/L-4-1872-Sheet-2.jpg (bottom left)
- https://www.frostjedi.com/L-4-1872-Sheet-3.jpg (top right)
- https://www.frostjedi.com/L-4-1872-Sheet-4.jpg (bottom left)

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry.. what's the question? If automated solutions don't work, generally it means you must resort to *manual* solutions.

Comment: You've already made a composite image of all four images in your example. How is that different from what you are asking? Are there more than four originals, are you looking to do something about the white space between images? Please expand on what your desired end image will be.

Comment: @shashin-ka - the lines aren't lined up. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdft6.jpg . I added a yellow circle to it. The two lines in that connect. Or at least they should. Presumably all that's needed is to figure out the optimal rotation that'll result in all such lines being connected. https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjA6a.jpg is a closeup of the area. Like the maps have a black background. Where there's a big blob of white that's not clearly a line or polygon or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to trying to automate the process is to just put the images together manually. This is not a tutorial, but a brief description of what I did.

Make a document in Photoshop the size of the final composite image. Import each sector of the map on a separate layer. Choose which layer is going to be the reference, and move and rotate the other layers to line up to the reference. This example isn't complete but shows the area you highlighted aligned..

[image: Composite of four maps adjusted for angle]